# Enable CORS for azure blob storage

Tags: angularjs, azure, cors, azure-blob-storage

Im totally new to `Azure Blob Storage` and Im having a problem in setting up the `CORS` for the angular client side. I am using this [module](https://github.com/kinstephen/angular-azure-blob-upload). I successfully generated a `sasToken` on my `nodejs` server.

Also I have checked these references : [Set Blob Service Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452235.aspx), [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Support for the Azure Storage Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Windows Azure Storage: Introducing CORS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors/) but I really find it confusing where to do/put those codes.

So far what I've done is this :

**IN THE AGULAR CONTROLLER:**

```
// this is the service that generate the sasToken from the server
getService.getSasToken(filename)
        .then(function (response) {
            // response = {
            //    sasToken : "asa7sya....",
            //    token: "the shared key",
            //    account: "the storage account name"
            // }

            function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
                    xhr.open(method, url, true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-ms-version", "2013-08-15");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", response.token);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("myaccount", response.account);
                } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
                    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
                    xhr.open(method, url, true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-ms-version", "2013-08-15");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", response.token);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("myaccount", response.account);
                } else {
                    xhr = null;
                }
                return xhr;
            }

            var xhr = createCORSRequest('PUT', 'https://foo.blob.core.windows.net?restype=service&comp=properties');
            if (!xhr) {
                throw new Error('CORS not supported');
            }else{
                // Response handlers.
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + xhr.responseText);
                    azureBlob.upload({
                        baseUrl: "https://foo.blob.core.windows.net/bar/"+filename,
                        sasToken: "?"+response.sasToken,
                        file: blobFile,
                        progress: function (progress) {
                            console.log("progress", progress);
                        },
                        complete: function (complete) {
                            console.log("complete", complete);
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log("error", error);
                        },
                        // blockSize: // What do I put here?
                    })
                };

                xhr.onerror = function() {
                    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../scripts/cors.xml", // local xml file 
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(xml){
                        console.log("xml", xml);
                        xhr.send(xml);
                    }
                });

            }
        },function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

**CORS.XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StorageServiceProperties>
    <Logging>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
        <Delete>true</Delete>
        <Read>false</Read>
        <Write>true</Write>
        <RetentionPolicy>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Days>7</Days>
        </RetentionPolicy>
    </Logging>
    <HourMetrics>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <IncludeAPIs>false</IncludeAPIs>
        <RetentionPolicy>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Days>7</Days>
        </RetentionPolicy>
    </HourMetrics>
    <MinuteMetrics>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <IncludeAPIs>true</IncludeAPIs>
        <RetentionPolicy>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Days>7</Days>
        </RetentionPolicy>
    </MinuteMetrics>
    <Cors>
        <CorsRule>
            <AllowedOrigins>*</AllowedOrigins>
            <AllowedMethods>GET,PUT,POST</AllowedMethods>
            <MaxAgeInSeconds>500</MaxAgeInSeconds>
            <ExposedHeaders>x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-customheader</ExposedHeaders>
            <AllowedHeaders>x-ms-meta-target*,x-ms-meta-customheader</AllowedHeaders>
        </CorsRule>
    </Cors>
    <DefaultServiceVersion>2013-08-15</DefaultServiceVersion>
</StorageServiceProperties>
```

The codes above is based on this [GUIDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452235.aspx)

However I am still getting this error :

[image]

Has anyone done this before? Please share your code guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as an FYI, CORS forces a pre-flight HTTP OPTIONS request for to be made prior to all cross origin requests, so you need to set OPTIONS as an allowed method as well `<AllowedMethods>GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS</AllowedMethods>` There is a section about pre-flight OPTIONS request in the [MDN article about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I added OPTIONS, still the same.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that your response to preflight request doesn't include 'Access-Control-Allow-origin' header which shows your preflight request failed. It means you didn't get permission from server side.

You said that your code are based on [Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452235.aspx). But the guide says Date or x-ms-date is required in
 request headers which doesn't appear in yours which made your preflight request rejected.

My suggestion is adding x-ms-date to your request headers and try again.
You can see [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server) to get details about 'preflight request' and 'actual request'.

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for the response, I figured that out and I made changes, I will update my question later. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this morning. Did a couple of research and find out no code bases changes were required.

The changes required were at the Azure Container level. As seen below:

[image]

Enter wildcards or specific ones, and this will get the things working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I looked for the same solution for NodeJS and haven't found.
Here is how to enable CORS (only http GET) for all origins:

```
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`, credential);
const props = await blobServiceClient.getProperties();
props.cors.push({ allowedOrigins: '*', allowedMethods: 'GET,OPTIONS', allowedHeaders: '', exposedHeaders: '', maxAgeInSeconds: 3600 });
const result = await blobServiceClient.setProperties(props);
console.log('Storage account', accountName, 'CORS enable result ...', result.errorCode || 'Done');
```

Comment: The code fails in the second line for me, can't even connect to the BlobServiceClient due to CORS failure.

Comment: @Kid this is server code. I guess you're trying to run this code via browser, this is very unsecure and I suppose many Azure SDK features just won't work via browser.

Answer (score -1):

I spent two days on this. I had to hardcode the origin in the blob storage cors setting.  The `*` would not work. Put your client url in the cors option versus `*` and I bet things will be better. `<AllowedOrigins>*</AllowedOrigins>` change to your localhost when in dev.

Also add `HEAD` to required methods